# Python web.py: how to close off the webserver after processing a request

Tags: python, web.py

I have setted up a web.py server in a desktop python 3.3 program that runs on localhost, it's purpose is to show a simple webpage in the browser based on info in the url and this just once.

Because the default activity of the web.py server seems to influence the good working of my program, i have to properly shut down the webservice **after** the one and only request it gets. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: `import sys; sys.exit(0)`, would stop the entire python script.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer this will stop his web server and he will not be able to serve the page.

Comment: Serving the page is the indeed the tricky part, i also tried to add a processor like `my_processor(handler): 
 result = handler()
 app.stop()
 return result`
I didn't served the page.

Comment: How about "serving" two pages: first, the page you want, then have THAT page request another resource from the server, by including e.g. `<iframe src="/die" height="0" width="0"/>`, which causes the server to not return anything and die?